# How to start a new row in HTML table when showing MySQL results?

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I am showing rows from a MySQL database into a HTML table

See my code below:

```
 <table border='1' width='100%'>
 <tr>    

for ($i = 1; $i <= mysql_num_rows($result667); $i++)
{
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result667);
$InterviewTime=$row['interview_time'];

echo"<td><input type='radio' name='Time' value='$time' required>$time</td> ";
}
  if ($i % 4 == 0) {
        echo '</tr><tr>'; // it's time no move to next row
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

The table is currently showing in one long row. How can I end the current row and start a new row `<tr>` after 4 columns?

Comment: The current result is one long row

Comment: You are using <tr> outside of loop , Add that in start of loop and add closing tag in end of loop.

Comment: where would <tr> need to go?

Comment: move if statement into for

Comment: correct , you have to move that inside of loop then it will be work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <table border='1' width='100%'>
       <tr>
       <?php
          for ($i = 1; $i <= mysql_num_rows($result667); $i++)
          {
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result667);
            $InterviewTime=$row['interview_time'];
            echo"<td><input type='radio' name='Time' value='$time' required>$time</td>";          
            if ($i % 4 == 0) {
              echo '</tr><tr>'; // it's time no move to next row
            }
          }
          ?>
          </tr>
    </table>
```

As i can see your if statement which checks for if `$i % 4 ==0` is out of the for loop. check this code works for you. and i have added a `</tr>` to close your opened tr tag at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code might help you , and try to write HTML code

```
<table border='1' width='100%'>
    <tr>    
        <?php
        for ($i = 1; $i <= mysql_num_rows($result667); $i++)
        {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result667);
        $InterviewTime=$row['interview_time'];

        echo"?>
        <td><input type='radio' name='Time' value='$time' required><?php $time; ?></td> <?php"
        }
        if ($i % 4 == 0) { 
        echo '?></tr><tr> <?php'; // it's time no move to next row
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just be simple

```
<table>
<?php for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++){ ?>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Above code will add `$total rows`. Just write between `<td></td>` tags